# MinGW portability

Tags: c++, mingw

I'm completely new to C++, but I have created a minor program, looking to port the program to other computers, but when I "install" the program I get this error...-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ missing, is there a file I should be including in the program itself, or is this a library I have to install on each computer? The computers that I expect to run the program will be windows xp. Source code of the file is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    _chdir("C:\\Program Files\\NCHSoftware\\Talk\\");
    string number = "start talk.exe -dial " + std::string(argv[1]+4);
    system(number.c_str());
    exit;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most people would do this with a shell script or .bat file, not a C++ program.

Comment: Have you been able to run the program on the machine where it was developed?  What is really at issue here are the linker settings/flags, not the source code.  Post the output of 'objdump -p *your_executable*  | grep NEEDED'

Comment: Do i do this from the command prompt? Forgive me but as I said i'm new to C++ this is in fact my first program. When I type this in cmd, nothing happens. The program runs fine on the machine I developed it in.

Comment: `exit;` What is this intended to do?

Comment: exit should't be there it does nothing for the program, it looks like the version i'm using is g++ 4.5.2. The only thing i'm interested in figuring out is how to make this program run on another computer, I tested and tried installing mingw on another computer, rebuilt the program and tried to run it, but i get a similar issue libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll was not found

Comment: The DLL(s)/LIB(s) location either need to be in the end users environment path (so they can be found by your executable) or statically linked during compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are shared lib's that would need to be on the host computer.

To learn how to compile a static version;
See here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html
Read the "-static-libgcc" & "-static-libstdc++" sections.

Comment: I read that too, I don't quite understand where I should be linking this.

Comment: Thank you I tried to search for an example of linking, I understood the concept, but didn't know how to do it, in the end I compiled it as g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ dial.cpp -o dial.exe, program runs fine. As I read it did make the file larger, but as that wasn't something that was an immediate concern, I was fine with it.